# How to add background quad to Starling Textfield

Tags: actionscript-3, starling-framework

I have a bunch of Starling textfields that I would like to add a background quad/color too but unsure how with the textfield being variable length.

I was going to use autosize but thats not available in starling. I would also like to add some padding to the textfield to so hoping someone knows how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You should give [Feathers UI](http://feathersui.com/) a try. it's very fast and you can use themes to skin your components.

It also comes with a few themes that you can use:

Check out the [Components Explorer](http://feathersui.com/examples/components-explorer/)